# Вызвать поток и завершить функцию

Tags: c++, многопоточность, boost

У меня есть код на C++, содержащий функцию. Эта функция должна вызвать функцию в другом потоке, а сама - завершиться. Как такое можно провернуть, используя `std::thread` или `boost::thread`?

Comment: Что значит "функция в другом потоке" ?

Comment: @Антон значит просто вызвать другую функцию и завершить ту, из которой вызывается.

Comment: Вызвать как, синхронно или асинхронно? Можно более подробную модель вызовов вашей программы.

Comment: У меня есть класс, при завершении одного из методов мне нужно вызвать метод другого класса и при этом завершить первый метод до окончания работы второго. Я пытался использовать boost::thread без join, но он просто обрывает выполнение второго метода на середине.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский а вы `detach` вызвали?